# Does entropy increase when multiplying two numbers?

Tags: number-theory, entropy, totient-function

The idea behind this question is to attach to a natural number in a "natural" way an entropy, such that "multiplication increases entropy". (Of course one can attach very different entropies to natural numbers such that multiplication reduces entropy, but I will try to give an argument, why this choice is natural.)
Let $n$ be a composite number $\ge 2$, $\phi$ the Euler totient function. Suppose a factorization algorithm $A$ outputs a number $X$, $1 \le X \le n-1$ with equal probability $\frac{1}{n-1-\phi(n)}$ such that $1 < \gcd(X,n) < n$. Then we can view $X$ as a random variable and attach the entropy to it $H(X_n):=H(n):= \log_2(n-1-\phi(n))$.

The motivation behind this definition comes from an analogy to physics:
I think that "one-way-functions" correspond to the "arrow of time" in physics.
Since "the arrow of time" increases entropy, so should "one-way-functions", if they exist. Since integer factorization is known to be a candidate for owf, my idea was to attach an entropy which would increase when multiplying two  numbers.

So my question is:

Do we have $H(mn) > H(n) + H(m)$ for all composite numbers $n \ge 2, m \ge 2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is equivalent to ask whether
$$
nm-1-\phi(nm) > (n-1-\phi(n))(m-1-\phi(m))
$$
for all composite numbers $m,n\ge2$. This inequality in turn is equivalent to
$$
(m - \phi(m)) \phi(n) + (n \phi(m) - \phi(nm) ) + (m - 1 - \phi(m)) + (n - 1 - \phi(n)) > 0,
$$
which is true as the first term in parentheses is positive and all other terms in parentheses are nonnegative. The fact that $n\phi(m) \ge \phi(nm)$ is not obvious, but it is easy to prove: it follows from
$$
\frac{\phi(m)}m = \prod_{p\mid m} \bigg( 1-\frac1p \bigg) \ge \prod_{p\mid nm} \bigg( 1-\frac1p \bigg) = \frac{\phi(nm)}{nm}.
$$

Comment: thank you for your answer